# How can I simply my functions/routes in a Python + Flask app please?

Tags: python, html, flask, routes

I have the following python and HTML code:

PYTHON

```
from bottle import route, run, template, request
import time

page = 1
block_name = "NONE"

@route ("/blocka")
def blocka ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block A")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block A"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/blockb")
def blockb ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block B")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block B"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/blockc")
def blockc ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block C")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block C"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/blockd")
def blockd ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block D")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block D"
    return "ok"

@route ("/blocke")
def blocke ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block E")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block E"
    return "ok"

@route ("/blockf")
def blockf ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block F")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block F"
    return "ok"

@route ("/blockg")
def blockg ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block G")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block G"
    return "ok"

@route ("/blockh")
def blockh ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block H")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block H"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/blocki")
def blocki ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block I")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block I"
    return "ok"

@route ("/blockj")
def blockj ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block J")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block J"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/blockk")
def blockk ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("Block K")
    page = 2
    block_name = "Block K"
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/menu")
def menu ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("MENU")
    return "ok"
    
@route ("/cancel")
def cancel ( ):
    global page
    global block_name
    print ("CANCEL")
    page = 1
    block_name = "NONE"
    return "ok"
    
# Handler for the home page
@route ("/")
def index():
    global page
    global block_name
    
    if page == 1:
        return template('index.html')
        
    if page == 2:
        header_data = {'block': block_name}
        return template('index2.html', data = header_data, name="TEST")

# Start the webserver
IP_ADDRESS = '192.168.1.129' # of your Pi
try:
    run(host=IP_ADDRESS, port=8080, reloader=True) 
except:
    print("Massive Error! WTF!!!")
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
  background-color: #1c1c17;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vw;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 12vh 12vh 12vh 12vh 12vh 12vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.cells {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 6vw;
}

</style>

</head>
<body >

<h2>Parcel Notification System</h2>
<h1>Select Block</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block A</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block B</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block C</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block D</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block E</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block F</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block G</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block H</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block I</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block J</div>
   <div class="cells" onclick="sendMotion('blocka');">Block K</div>
   <div class="cells" style="background-color:gray" class="grid-item" onclick="sendCommand('menu');">Menu</div>
</div>

<script>

function sendMotion(action) {
   request = new XMLHttpRequest ( );
   request.open ("GET", action, true);
   request.send ( );
   location.reload(true);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and as you can see I have a separate route and function for every button. I am sure there is a better way of doing this and have a single function handle whatever comes back from the webpage to decide which button was pressed. However, i cannot figure this out and I've search for hours for a solution.

If anyone can put my out of my misery and explain how to do this please i will be extremely grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use global variables in web applications you will get unexpected results if concurrent requests occur. Or in other words: your code is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You should considering using HTTP headers and sending params from your frontend (html code here) to your backend (Flask here).

Look at [request args](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args) for Flask.

Basically, your Flask code will be something like this

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/handle-blocks')
def handle_blocks():
  param1 = request.args.get('param1')
  ...
```

And frontend, using [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) :

```js
const apiUrl = 'your-api-published-url'; // can be localhost:8000

const request = new Request(`$apiUrl`, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: '{"param1": "param1_value"}'
});

const response = await fetch(request);

// handle response status ...
// 500 : internal server error
// 400 < error < 500
// 200: ok
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a try